Expanding a non-polynomial fraction
On my physics slides, the derivative of the momentum,
$ p = m_0 \frac{  v }{ \sqrt{ 1- \frac{ v^2 } { c^2 } } } $ with respect to v is given as $$ \frac{dp}{dv} = \frac{ m_0  }{ ({ 1- \frac{ v^2 } { c^2 } }) ^\frac{3}{2}} $$
A manual solution (confirmed by using tools such as Maxima), gives me an expanded solution:
$$ \frac{dp}{dv} = \frac{ m_0  }{ \sqrt{ 1- \frac{ v^2 } { c^2 } } } + \frac{ m_0  }{ ({ 1- \frac{ v^2 } { c^2 } }) ^\frac{3}{2}} \frac{v^2}{c^2} $$
It is fairly simple to go from the expanded solution to a single fraction and verify that they are equal. However, out of curiosity, I was wondering how simple it is to deduce the expanded solution from the single fraction? In other words, finding A and B in
$$  \frac{ m_0  }{ ({ 1- \frac{ v^2 } { c^2 } }) ^\frac{3}{2}}  =  m_0\frac{  A  }{ \sqrt{ 1- \frac{ v^2 } { c^2 } } } + m_0\frac{  B  }{ ({ 1- \frac{ v^2 } { c^2 } }) ^\frac{3}{2}}  $$
I attempted to find a generic solution by letting $ x =  { 1- \frac{ v^2 } { c^2 } } $ and expanding the fraction manually to no avail. I hoped this would work out simply because the $ \frac{v^2}{c^2} $ factor would just be $ 1- x $ on the second fraction. Any clues?

I'm going to use $x$ to denote the square root of the thing you called $x$. That'll simply divide all the exponents by $2$. (I did this without thinking, and @JMP pointed it out for me.) You could replace every $x$ in everything below with $x^2$ to get the same argument for the thing you chose to call $x$ --- it all still works.
That gives you
$$
\frac{m_0}{x^3} = m_0 \frac{A}{x} + m_0 \frac{B}{x^3},
$$
right? Multiply through by $\frac{x^3}{m_0}$ to get
$$
1 = x^2 A +  B,
$$
Now $x$ is something that can vary with the velocity $v$, but this equality must hold for every value of $x$ (or at least enough values to make the following claim work). It's an equality of polynomials, so the coefficients on the two sides must match, giving $A = 0, B = 1$.
That doesn't seem too hard to me.
Details of the claim: In general, if two degree-$k$ polynomials agree at $k+1$ points, then they're equal. And the reason is simple: the difference between them is a polynomial of degree $k$ that is $0$ at $k+1$ points. A nonzero degree-$k$ polynomial has at most $k$ distinct roots, by the fundamental theorem of algebra. So the difference polynomial must be the zero polynomial.
Post-comment rewrite, with a little cleanup
That gives you
$$
\frac{m_0}{x^{3/2}} = m_0 \frac{A}{x^{1/2}} + m_0 \frac{B}{x^{3/2}},
$$
right? Multiply through by $\frac{x^{3/2}}{m_0}$ to get
$$
1 = x A +  B,
$$
or
$$
Ax + (B-1) = 0.
$$
Now $x$ is something that can vary with the velocity $v$, but this equality must hold for every value of $x$. By picking at least two different $v$ values, you can see that it's true for two values of $x$, so the degree-1 polynomial on the left has two distinct roots. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, which says that a nonzero degree-k polynomial has at most $k$ distinct roots, this says that the polynomial must be zero, hence $A = 0$ and $B = 1$.

Your $x$ is OP's $\sqrt{x}$

Thanks...I'll edit.

I'm not sure I follow your first step. Squaring the sum of the fractions on the r.h.s wouldn't equal the sum of their squares. Also, as you can see, the solution is $ A = 1,  B = 1-x $ for $ x= 1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2} $ $ A= 0, B =1 $ would most certainly work as well, but I was wondering how to get to the first solution from just the single fraction.

I've rewritten; see post-comment addition.

You said you wanted to find $A$ and $B$ in the displayed equation. I did so, and in fact found the only possible values for them ... perhaps mistakenly assuming that $A$ and $B$ were constants. If not, there are infinitely many solutions: pick $A$ to be any expression, and let $B = 1 - Ax$. But that doesn't seem very interesting. I mean, we could chose $A = \sin(x)$ and $B = 1 - x \sin(x)$, but why would we?

Also: you're more or less inventing the "method of partial fractions" here, but inverted.

Your update has helped me finally figure out what I'm missing - most importantly, for this to work $ A $ and $ B $ must be allowed to be functions of $ x $, not necessarily constants. Knowing that, there are infinitely many solutions as you have mentioned. Given that, there is no "travelator" way to go from the single-fraction solution to the expanded solution I get when differentiating manually. I just need to arbitrarily set one of the coefficients and find the other such that $ xA(x) + B(x) = 1 $ is satisfied. Thank you.

As to why would I go from the single-fraction solution to the expanded solution, the two-fraction form is what you immediately get when differentiating the original function with respect to $ v $.  It was simple for me to go from that to the single-fraction form, but I didn't fully understand what going the other way involved.
